# Java projects forcing dependents to adopt Java versions?

Tags: java, maven, compatibility, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

Here's a question.  Suppose I have a Maven project ("A") that pulls in a different Maven project ("B") as a dependency.  Both currently use Java 7 to compile.  If Project B switches to Java 8, does it force Project A to use Java 8 as well?

If so, is there a way around it - that is, have Project B generate code that Project A can use, without downgrading Project B to Java 7 or upgrading Project A to Java 8?  For example, having Project B do some form of "source 1.8 target 1.7", for example.  (javac doesn't seem to like that, and I can't find an alternative compiler that will - for example, plexus-compiler-eclipse doesn't support Java 8, but that's another issue altogether; the issue is that of decoupling the generated bytecode from the source version that was used to generate it)

Comment: If B is using Java 8, the best you may be able to achieve is to compile A with jdk8 but target = 1.7. That will probably be pointless, though, since the classes in B won't run under JDK7. So, in short, if B switches, either A stays at an older version, or it also has to switch.

Answer (score 3):

Java is backwards compatible but not forwards compatible. When running a program with a JVM (JRE) version older than what the program was compiled with you will get an error, (the usual Unsupported major.minor version error). Its quite logical. Some new byte code directives might have been introduced in the newer JRE version which the old JRE doesn't know about (especially with all the new Java 8 fancy stuff).

If you have a dependency that is compiled with Java 8 (although I doubt any of the popular dependencies have already been migrated to exclusively use Java 8!) then you have to upgrade your project to use Java 8.

On the other hand, if your project is upgraded to Java 8, then any dependencies, irrespective if they were compiled with Java 8, 7 or 6, will work, due to the backwards compatibility guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

> If Project B switches to Java 8, does it force Project A to use Java 8 as well?

Yes, unless you can compile Project B with `-source 1.7 -target 1.7,` which means you can't use Java 8 features in B.

It has nothing to do with Maven.